# Change the last two letters in a string in a column when entrie exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table A that contains a few columns with entries. In column 1 is the campaign name which is unique in the table. Now I want to change the last two letters in a string in another column (let´s say column 2) when the campaign name exists in another table (Table B)(If the campaign name is not in table B, nothing should happen). The "new" two last letters are part of a string in column 2 (1 is also the campaign name) in table B. 
-> How can I do this?

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2           |
+--------------------------------+---------------+------
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||NewsletterDE   |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||LifecyclemailUK|
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||BKMailCH       |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||LifecyclemailDE|
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||BKMailDE       |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||NewsletterFR   |
```

And table B contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2           |
+--------------------------------+---------------+------
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||LifecyclemailCH|
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||NewsletterDE   |
```

I want a query that will change table A to:

```
|col1                           ||col2           |
+--------------------------------+---------------+------
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||NewsletterDE   |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||LifecyclemailCH|
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||BKMailCH       |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||LifecyclemailDE|
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||BKMailDE       |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||NewsletterDE   |
```

This what I got so far:

```
UPDATE table A INNER JOIN table B ON A.col1  = B.col1 SET A.col2 = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(A.col2), RIGHT(B.col2,2));
```

-> But this is not working correctly....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
update tablea a 
join tableb b on a.col1 = b.col1
set a.col2 = concat(
               susbtr(a.col2, 1, length(a.col2) - 2),
               right(b.col2, 2)
             )
```